# Abp.io Microservices - ActivatorChain: "Pages.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpTenantController"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Apologies for the wounded question, it is my first time here. I created a microservices application using abp.io. There is a sign up page and when the details are supplied an account is created. However, when logging in, tenant switch finds the tenant but logiing throws error:

An exception was thrown while activating Pages.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpTenantController.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Pages.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpTenantController.
---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Pages.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpTenantController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.MultiTenancy.IAbpTenantAppService abpTenantAppService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.MultiTenancy.IAbpTenantAppService)'.

What package am i missing? Apologies

I checked the api routing in the gateway. Api route for tenants is set to

"saas": {
"ClusterId": "saas",
"Match": {
"Path": "/api/multi-tenancy/{*any}"
}

Additonal information:
when I test the api from swagger, the following endpoints throw the same error:
https://localhost:49555/api/abp/multi-tenancy/tenants/by-id/
https://localhost:7003/api/abp/multi-tenancy/tenants/by-name/

500 error code
Error message:
{
"error": {
"code": null,
"message": "An internal error occurred during your request!",
"details": null,
"data": {
"ActivatorChain": "Pages.Abp.MultiTenancy.AbpTenantController"
},
"validationErrors": null
}
}

Comment: This is resolved, I was missing a DependsOn[typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiMultiTenancyModule)] in Saas module. I had the package installed

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, I was missing the following in my Saas module:

```
DependsOn[typeof(AbpAspNetCoreMvcUiMultiTenancyModule)]
```

I had the package installed.